# What does "cosmologies" mean in this particular context?

Tags: meaning, word-meaning, definition

Consider the following extract:

> A skillful cook can make delectable dishes without quite being able to
> tell us how. (Conversely, the possession of a good recipe book is not
> sufficient to make a good cook.) By embedded understanding, I mean,
> this practical knowledge that remains pre-reflective and inarticulate.
> It is an understanding we acquire by being initiated into the
> practices of a society. The term 'common sense' is broader and covers
> embedded understanding but also, at the very least, our spontaneous
> and ad hoc reflections, including reflections that are closely aligned
> to our practices, which might be called practical reflections. It
> usually also includes stories, epics, folk tales, legends, myths that
> have been passed on from one generation to another and with the help
> of which we make sense of and evaluate the entire universe. Such
> nearly systematic but non-theoretical reflections which knit together
> in a seamless web the physical, biological, social, mental and
> spiritual worlds may be called **cosmologies**. **Cosmologies** frequently
> inform and become part of a society's common sense.

According to Merriam-Webster, **cosmology** has the following meanings:

> 1. A branch of metaphysics that deals with the nature of the universe.
> 2. A theory or doctrine describing the natural order of the universe.
> 3. A branch of astronomy that deals with the origin, structure, and space-time relationships of the universe. (also : a theory dealing with these matters)

Which sense of the word is the author referring to by **cosmologies**? Why is it being used in a plural form here?

Thank you in advance. :)

Comment: What is the source, who is the author? Please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of those meanings.  The author is using a word in a specfic and non standard way, which is why he/she defines cosmologies as

> Nearly systematic but non-theoretical reflections which knit together in a seamless web the physical, biological, social, mental and spiritual worlds

This is related to the first dictionary definition: a metaphysical system concerning the nature of the universe.

Comment: Thanks @James K